# Button setText with Spannable doesn't work for Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, button, android-5.0-lollipop, spannable

I have a simple `Button`:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/test"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

and try to change text property by:

```
SpannableString span = new SpannableString(text);
span.setSpan(new AbsoluteSizeSpan(8, true), 5, 10, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
testButton.setText(span);
```

It works on Android 4.3 but doesn't on 5.0.

The interesting thing is when I change implementation from `Button` to `TextView` it works fine on 5.0. Seems to be something with `Button` in Lollipop.

Comment: "It works with Android 4.3, but doesn't with 5.0." -- please define what "doesn't" means here. If you mean that your `AbsoluteSizeSpan` is lost, that does not shock me, as Android 5.0 seems to want to control the captions more, such as forcing them to all caps.

Comment: @CommonsWare yes, span is ignored.

Comment: I would expect that there are many developers who are irritated with Android 5.0's default of all-caps for the caption. If there is a workaround for blocking that behavior, it might also allow your `AbsoluteSizeSpan` to continue working.

Comment: You can turn off all caps. Search on Google or SO.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

By default, Material buttons are styled to show text in all-caps. However, there is a bug in the `AllCapsTransformationMethod` used for capitalization that causes it to discard `Spannable` data.

You can override the default button styling and disable all-caps by specifying `android:textAllCaps="false"` on your `Button`.

```
<Button
    ...
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

Comment: Another wtf Android moment...when you have TextView with setAllCaps set to true, Spannables stops working. In my case was a ForegroundColorSpannable. Thank you for answer.

Comment: For more discussion, please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257606/imagespan-not-working-on-android-5/32867216?noredirect=1#comment53573775_32867216