# spannablestring is not working for programmatically created button

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I know SpannableString is possible to set different text size in one textview but if textview is added programmatically it's not working.

```
String s = "Best Ever";
SpannableString ss1 =  new SpannableString(s);
ss1.setSpan(new RelativeSizeSpan(2f), 0, 4, 0); // set size
ss1.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, 4, 0); // set color
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);
tv.setText(ss1);
```

Comment: what api version? 5+?

Comment: they changed it in v5, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29007746/button-settext-with-spannable-dosent-work-for-android-5-0-lollipop

Answer (score 32, accepted):

As you can see, It's work on Button and TextView for API17 but work on TextView only on API21

Interesting! I notice that the button on API 21 is all caps..So remove all caps.

By default, Material buttons are styled to show text in all-caps. However, there is a bug in the AllCapsTransformationMethod  ( [bug details](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67509) )used for capitalization that causes it to discard Spannable data.

You can override the default button styling by disabling allCaps mode, which is true by default for Material-styled widgets.

From code,

```
txt.setAllCaps(false);
```

From XML,

```
<View
    ...
    android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks! was about to bang my head!

Comment: please update your answer because no `android:allCaps` attribute.  I've found that `android:textAllCaps` is the right one.

Comment: @isnotmenow thanks for initiating, i updated my answer :)

Comment: I have been trying to figure this out for a day now. I knew it would be something silly like this. In my case, I was trying to make the decimal for a number 50% smaller. Who would've thought you can capitalize a number in Android!

Comment: What's the source for the mentioned `AllCapsTransformationMethod` bug that discards the `Spannable` data? Is there one?

Comment: This is a known bug with the textAllCaps attribute, specifically with AllCapsTransformationMethod.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=67509  @もっくん